# Excel VBA Type Mismatch Error 13

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm kind of new to VBA, and I am having some problems working with multiple workbooks at once. I had a code fully functional that essentially just takes data from one sheet to another given certain conditions are met.

Now I am trying to update the code to move from one workbook to another, and thus I have begun to declare workbooks instead of just referencing sheet names.

Now I am getting various errors.

**code follows.**

before (worked)

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrendDataByDay()

   'determine date of data pulled
    Dim CurrentDate As String

    CurrentDate = Sheets("Daily Pull").Range("B23").Value
```

after (fails; now using 2 workbooks)

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrendDataByDay()
    Dim wbDaily, wbHistory As Workbook

    'declare daily and history workbooks
    Set wbDaily = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\Daily Focus Metrics\Focus Metrics History by Facility.xlsm"
    Set wbHistory = Application.Workbooks("Focus Metrics History by Facility.xlsm")

    'determine date of data pulled
    Dim CurrentDate As String

    'error here!
    CurrentDate = Workbooks(wbDaily).Sheets("Daily Pull").Range("B23").Value
```

I also tried:

```
CurrentDate = wbDaily.Sheets("Daily Pull").Range("B23").Value
```

I need to understand why I cannot simply declare these workbooks and specify the workbook that a sheet belongs to in this way. I would also like to know the ideal way to reference and dim workbooks without having to "select" each workbook when copying or pasting data.

Comment: `Workbooks(wbDaily).Sheets("Daily Pull").Range("B23").Value` should just be `wbDaily.Sheets("Daily Pull").Range("B23").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Workbooks(wbDaily)` to `wbDaily`

Also a small note .. unlike VB.Net

```
Dim wbDaily, wbHistory As Workbook
```

Is the same as

```
Dim wbDaily As Variant
Dim wbHistory As Workbook
```

so you can change it to

```
Dim wbDaily As Workbook, wbHistory As Workbook
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It appears that I had tried the proper method of wbDaily.etc, but I was having issues because of the ambiguous declaration of wbDaily. Using Dim as you suggested did the trick.